# How can change height and position of createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a createBottomTabNavigator on my project.by default tabs have specific height and bottom position .
how can I change position and height of it
my code:

```
const Navigate=createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home:{screen:Home,navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Home',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="md-home" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        }  },
    Camera:{screen:Camera,navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="md-add-circle" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        } },
     Profile: {  
        screen:Profile,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="md-person" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        }  
      },
}
,{
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red',
      inactiveTintColor: 'cyan',
      activeBackgroundColor:'lightgreen',
      showLabel:false,
      keyboardHidesTabBar:false,
      tabStyle:{
            backgroundColor:'orange',
            height:40,
      },
    },
  },
  },
);
```

export default createAppContainer(Navigate);

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height in the style object, not the tabBarOptions.
Refer to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html for the styles object.

I did it like this in my app

```
const navigatorConfig = {
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
switch (routeName) {
....
  }
style: {
  height: responsiveHeight(7.5),
  borderTopWidth: 0,
},
}}
enter code here
```